# Откуда на самом деле пошло выражение «и никаких гвоздей»?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, литература

Пожалуй, самый известный случай использования этой фразы — в [поэме](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5,_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5_(%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) В. В. Маяковского «Необычайное приключение, бывшее с Владимиром Маяковским летом на даче» (1920):

> Светить всегда,
> светить везде,
> до дней последних донца,
> светить —
> и никаких гвоздей!
> Вот лозунг мой —
> и солнца!

Однако, если верить [Викисловарю](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F), данный фразеологизм «встречается в литературе и в предшествуюшие годы, например, в пьесе А. Т. Аверченко "Гололёдица" (1911), в рассказе Е. И. Маурина "Одна" (1913) и др.»

Так откуда всё же взялось это выражение? Интуиция подсказывает, что это крылатая фраза из какого-то литературного шлягера, в котором она наверняка имела и прямой смысл — вот только из какого?

**UPD**: Насчёт затерянного литературного источника (предполагаемого «шлягера») всё больше сомневаюсь, новая гипотеза — возможно, на рынках к некому товару продавцы любили втайне добавлять гвозди, чтобы завысить вес. «Продвинутые» покупатели, зная этот трюк, могли заранее предупреждать, чтобы их даже не пытались таким образом обмануть. Впрочем, это всё ещё догадки, и я даже не знаю, что это мог быть за товар.

Comment: Об источнике ничего не могу сказать. На мой взгляд, "никаких гвоздей" - видоизменённое, упрощенное "никаких загвоздок" (затруднений, помех).

*ЗАГВО́ЗДКА, загвоздки, жен. 1. То, что вколачивается, вбивается; затычка (спец. и обл.). 2. Удар кулаком, тумак (прост. фам.). 3. Препятствие, досадная помеха, затруднение; задача, над которой надо подумать, трудный вопрос (разг.)*. - Толковый словарь Ушакова.

Answer (score 4):

Второй ответ

Многие считают, что Маяковский является автором фразеологического сочетания «и никаких гвоздей», но это не так. Поэт использовал его в известном стихотворении, написанном в 1920 году, но фразеологизм встречался в литературе раньше, о чем говорится в Викисловаре. [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/и_никаких_гвоздей](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Так кто же автор фразеологизма? Познакомившись с указанными произведениями, можно сделать такой вывод: автора нет, **это присказка**, то есть особая словесная форма народной речи.

**Обратимся к воспоминаниям К. Чуковского, записанным в его дневниках.** Декабрь 1920 года. Писатель приглашает Маяковского в Петербург, чтобы выступить в «Доме Искусств».

«Маяковский вышел — очень молодой (на вид 24 года), плечи ненормально широки, развязный, но не слишком… Потом начались стихи. Патетическую часть прослушали скучая, но когда началась ёрническая вторая часть о Чикаго — публика пришла в умиление. Я заметил, что **всех радуют те места, где Маяковский пользуется интонациями разговорной речи нашей эпохи, это кажется и ново, и свежо, и дерзко:** ***— И никаких гвоздей***. Должно быть, когда Крылов или Грибоедов воспроизводили естественные интонации своей эпохи — это производило такой же эффект».

**В пьесе Аверченко «Гололедица» (1911 год)** редактор Миколаев хвалится перед подчиненным своим положением: «Видишь, это мой кабинет. Ты это понимай, Мурзакин!  – Да-с. Свезло вам. –  Да, брат... Попал я в жилу – ***и никаких гвоздей!»***

**У Ф. Д. Крюкова в очерке «Новым строем» (1917 год)** записан разговор крестьян о современной жизни: «Они учителю нашему личность набок свернули: ходит теперь с завязанной шеей. — Вот оно, равнение-то. — Равнение, а молодняк у Ольшанки весь скотом вытравили. Свобода ***и — никаких гвоздей***.  Слышатся вздохи — тяжкие, подавленные. В самом деле, мудрена жизнь стала. Как будто и свобода, а утехи мало в том, и жизнь по-прежнему трудна и невылазна.

**А вот в следующем произведении (Евгений Маурин «Одна», 1913 год)**  фразеологизм так и назван – **присказка**. Сюжет там такой.

Служащая Мария Алексеевна живет одна, жизнь как будто проходит мимо, даже поговорить не с кем. По узкой, полутемной лестнице взбирается она на седьмой этаж, где ютятся «комнаты от домовладельца». Чай заварен, на столе аккуратно разложено масло, хлеб, колбаса. И вдруг – стук в дверь. Это студент, симпатичный парень, она встречала его раньше. Он зашел, чтобы попросить денег в долг: «Я, конечно, понимаю, что это странно, но... Не заплатили за урок, ***и никаких гвоздей***. Словом, нужны деньги. Если можете, выручите по-соседски до завтра... Ей-Богу, отдадим ***и... никаких гвоздей».*** Марья Алексеевна очень рада, что может помочь кому-то, приглашает попить с ней чаю. Студент колеблется, но всё-таки говорит: «Конечно, отчего же. И чайку можно... Только я сначала деньги товарищу отдам, и сейчас же вернусь опять... ***И никаких гвоздей!***  – с этой присказкой он поспешно поворачивается и выскальзывает за дверь.

**Итак, это присказка.**  Но не как зачин для сказок, а как языковой элемент. В последнем примере мы видим, что студент трижды использует это выражение с разным смыслом: не заплатили – и никаких объяснений, ничего не  поделаешь; отдадим деньги обязательно; отдам деньги и тут же вернусь, никаких в том сомнений.

Поэтому смысл у присказки **многозначный, а происхождение неясное**. Чей-то случайный афоризм, какая-то бытовая ситуация, где присутствовали реальные гвозди. Например: никакие отговорки, что гвоздей нет, не принимаются; или доска должна быть гладкой, безо всяких гвоздей. Однако афоризм прижился в речи, реальный его смысл стал неважен, отошел на второй план, но появилось **обобщенное, условное** значение.

Что касается Маяковского, то присказка, использованная в известном стихотворении, как бы **обрела автора** в том плане, что утвердилась в новом статусе – как **словарный фразеологизм с вполне конкретным значением:** (разг.) непременно, несомненно, обязательно, несмотря ни на что, безо всяких возражений.

Comment: Очень похоже на правду. Кстати, прочитал, что знаменитый авиаконструктор Туполев, похоже, тоже любил эту присказку. Ю. Н. Флаксерман:
«<…> Когда состоялось решение о строительстве серии разведчиков, немецкие инженеры приехали в ЦАГИ. А. Н. Туполев … показывал конструкции основных узлов аппарата. Он был немногословен и, желая подчеркнуть простоту конструкций, говорил: "Вот лонжерон крыла, на нем располагаются нервюрки, а на них - гофрированная обшивка, все просто и никаких гвоздей". [продолжение ниже]

Comment: [продолжение] Затем так же о конструкции хвостового оперения и опять: "Как видите, все просто и никаких гвоздей".
Немцы с удивлением просили разъяснить: в металлическом самолете гвозди не могут применяться, а господин Туполев почему-то все время говорит "никаких гвоздей"? За столом раздался дружный хохот. Немецким инженерам разъяснили, что означает русская присказка "никаких гвоздей"». (Источник: http://monino.ru/index.sema?a=articles&pid=15&id=74.)

Comment: Спасибо, очень смешная ситуация!

Answer (score 2):

> Интуиция подсказывает, что это крылатая фраза из какого-то
> литературного шлягера,

Мне интуиция подсказывает, что, будь оно так, это шлягер был бы известен и упоминался бы как первоисточник во всех справочниках.

> в котором она наверняка имела и прямой смысл

А вот с этим готов согласиться. Мне кажется вполне очевидным, что здесь отсылка идет к традициям русского зодчества, где огромные по тем временам конструкции создавались без единого гвоздя. Есть, конечно, маленькое возражение, что "никаких гвоздей"  имеет несколько иной смысл, чем "без единого гвоздя", но такой переход я готов допустить без дополнительного обоснования.

ПС

В сети гуляет несколько альтернативных версий, более занимательных, чем правдоподобных. Так, по одной из таких версий, выражение восходит к петровским временам. Петр-де издал указ, запрещающий жителям только что построенного Петербурга использование гвоздей при изготовлении обуви. Что объяснялось заботой о деревянных мостовых. Указа того никто не видел, да и сама постановка вопроса кажется малоправдоподобной. Ну какой вред от металлических подковок мостовым? К тому же - сделанным из корабельного бруса (а другой туда не шел)?

Comment: Была тоже мысль про «без единого гвоздя», превратившееся в какой-то ситуации в «никаких гвоздей» (скажем, приказывая строителям обойтись без гвоздей в неком проекте), но как-то это… неостроумно, что ли. С чего бы подобный случай отложился у многих в памяти? А вот про шлягер согласен, время всё же недавнее, хотя случаи вроде разные были, но всё больше с картинами эпохи Возрождения.

Answer (score 2):

Интересно то, что  фразеологизмы «и никаких гвоздей» и «гвоздь программы/сезона» **возникают где-то конце XIX — начале XX в**., раньше они в литературе не встречаются.

При этом Виноградов рассматривает «и никаких гвоздей»  в статье про идиому **«и никаких».** Там он и про Маяковского вспоминает,  а идиому "и никаких" по происхождению считает **«военно-командной» формулой.** Это выражение использовалось и в художественной литературе XIX века, например у Чехова: — Что ж? Единовременно пятьсот в зубы или двадцать пять помесячно — **и никаких**. Очень просто».

Статья Виноградова: http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=i_nikakih&vol=1

Фразеологизм **«гвоздь программы»**  связывают с Эйфелевой башней. Впервые фраза про "гвоздь чего-то" появилась в ходе Всемирной выставки 1889 года в Париже. Звучала она так: "le clou de l'exposition", то есть "гвоздь выставки".  Башня показалась посетителям очень похожей на гигантский гвоздь – шляпка лежит на земле, острие торчит в небо.
https://zen.yandex.ru/media/litinteres/gvozd-programmy-otkuda-vzialos-eto-vyrajenie-5e249d616d29c100ada9aa71

Гвоздь программы – это нечто особенное, исключительное,  а никаких гвоздей – это никаких исключений, возражений,  непременно, обязательно, несмотря ни на что.

Во всяком случае, что-то общее между этим «гвоздями» просматривается.

А вот при чем тут **Никоновская летопись**, мне уж совсем неясно. Ссылки на источник этой версии нет в ответе. В письменных памятниках фразеологизм нигде не фиксируется, появился он недавно, да и Виноградов об этом же говорит. Сначала в литературе мы встречаем выражение "и никаких", гвозди потом добавились.

**Виноградов:** "Например, идиома и никаких! (в значении `вопрос исчерпан, больше не о чем говорить: все решено, все ясно; и баста!) в современной устной фамильярной речи **как бы ищет предмета**, к которому может быть отнесено определение в род. пад. мн. числа (никаких). Отсюда возникают странно-синонимические выражения **и никаких гвоздей!** (ср. у Маяковского: Светить — и никаких гвоздей! Вот лозунг мой и солнца!) или "и никаких испанцев!"

Comment: Очень интересно, спасибо за наводку! Об идиоме «и никаких испанцев» впервые слышу; забавно, что и она появляется у Маяковского — на этот раз в «Пятом Интернационале»: «Швейцария. // Закована в горный панцирь. // Италия... // Сапожком на втором планце... // И уже в тумане: // Испания... // Испанцы... // А потом океан — и никаких испанцев». И тоже как-то словно не к месту, не из этой оперы)

Comment: Про «поиск предмета»: может, и так, но даже в этом будто бы узком смысле можно ещё выделить разные оттенки. Можно сказать «никаких» про что-то лишнее, можно — про споры и пререкания, а можно — про недозволенные методы/действия/мероприятия. И гвозди или испанцев не везде подставишь, с ними что-то гораздо более конкретное связано, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Да, я думаю, что вы правы.  Просмотрев литературу, где использовался этот фразеологизм, я склоняюсь к выводу, гвозди были вполне конкретные.  Но это скорее народное творчество, когда бытовая ситуации обобщается, приобретает условность и метафоричность, и тогда начинается ее особое существование в виде присказки. Например, говорят: Интересно девки пляшут (по 4 штуки в ряд). Или: С чего это баня-то упала (сруб же был новый)?

Comment: Метафорическая  форма имеет новый,  обобщенный  смысл, а именно  «интересно получается» или  «с какой стати появились эти проблемы?». То есть присказка  непосредственно не связана с обозначенным  в ней содержанием.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, корни уходят в более глубокую древность - в Никоновскую летопись, где говорится о знамении сыну князя Михайла Тверского  в 6879 году - пятнах на  солнце в виде гвоздя: "места черны, аки гвозди, а мгла стояла по ряду с 2 месяца..." Это было страшное знамение, запрещающее поход. Отсюда и значение "никаких гвоздей" = никаких препятствий.

Comment: Ого куда смотрите! Был бы готов поверить, если бы обнаружились хоть какие-то «промежуточные звенья эволюции» между местами чёрными, аки гвозди, и «никаких гвоздей» — за несколько сот лет-то.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что поговорка родилась по поводу этого знамения - я о "корнях", гвоздь связан с мифологическими (гвозди Спасителя) и обрядовыми традициями, с ворожбой, со знамениями испытаний, а в советские времена всё это было отнесено к суевериям и невежественной болтовне, потому и родилась эта поговорка "и никаких гвоздей", нечего придумывать препятствия-суеверия.

Comment: Маяковский как раз в "Окнах Роста" работал, антирелигиозные плакаты сочинял, ему это было близко, он знал поговорку.