# И никаких гвоздей! О категоричности, выраженной в гвоздях

Tags: фразеология

```
        Но зато уже не будет ни загадок, ни ошибок —
        только ровная дорога до последнего звонка.
        Б. Окуджава
```

**Жизнь как  гладкая  доска...  И НИКАКИХ ГВОЗДЕЙ!**

Кто же откажется от такой ровной дороги? Если только поэт и художник какой. (Но им это нужно для вдохновения.)

Каково **происхождение** этого фразеологического сочетания? Все толкователи, как мне думается, ходят **вокруг да около,** а хотелось бы услышать что-нибудь короткое и однозначно уверенное: **верно так, и никаких гвоздей!**  В идеале — одно-два предложения.

Обсуждение **на форумах:**

```
Ну и раньше тоже конечно было, при царе Горохе небось еще, наверное ещё 
когда гвозди были деревянными.
```

[Откуда на самом деле пошло выражение «и никаких гвоздей»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462139/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9)

[Как появилась такая фраза: "точка - и никаких гвоздей!"?](https://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4374195-kak-pojavilas-takaja-fraza-tochka-i-nikakih-gvozdej.html)

**Большой универсальный словарь русского языка.**
И НИКАКИХ ГВОЗДЕЙ, част., разг.
Употр. в конце предложения для сообщения содержащемуся в нём приказанию, требованию, пожеланию и т. п. экспрессивно окрашенной категоричности, исключающей всякие возражения.

**Большой словарь русских поговорок.** [И] никаких гвоздей.
Разг. Без всяких возражений; несмотря ни на что.

Comment: ещё "последний гвоздь в крышку гроба"

Comment: premier clouau cerseil (первый гвоздь гроба) - Тютчев, латынь правда я не могу подобную найти пока)

Comment: ошибка там, не clouau , а clāvus, ī m.
1) гвоздь ( ferreus Cs)
clavo c. ejicitur погов. C — гвоздь гвоздём же (= клин клином) вышибается
trabali clavo figĕre — см. trabalis
clavi indices numĕri annorum L — гвозди, показывающие число лет (по унаследованному от этрусков обычаю, римляне ежегодно, в сентябрьские иды, вбивали в стену храма Юпитера гвоздь; по этим гвоздям и велся счет годам

Comment: cerseil - сердце. Гвоздь в сердце. Имеются ввиду скорее всего отсылки к гвоздям которыми прибивали к кресту Христа. Доска без гвоздей ~ не распятье.

Comment: "Устанет то, и хочет ночь прилечь, тупая сонница. Вдруг — я во всю светаю мочь — и снова день трезвонится. Светить всегда, светить везде, до дней последних донца, светить — и никаких гвоздей! Вот лозунг мой — и солнца! " светаю мочь, день трезвонится, светить до дней последних до конца...

Comment: Гвозди  вещь сакральная, метафорический предмет. Но все-таки почему это символ категоричности? Последний гвоздь как последнее слово, больше гвоздей (слов) не надо?  Но смущает слово "никаких".

Comment: У Маяковского отсылки к религиозной тематике: В праздник красьте сегодняшнее число.
Творись,
распятью равная магия.
Видите -
гвоздями слов
прибит к бумаге я.

Comment: https://sever.foma.ru/kizhi-neizvestnoe-o-samom-izvestnom-hramovom-ansamble-russkogo-severa/

Comment: У них были деревянные гвозди, железные где купишь)

Comment: Не было деревянных пишут. И храм строили не известно почему без гвоздей, одна версия утилитарная - дорого, другая - что в этом был сакральный смысл.

Comment: Из статьи: Весь лемех изначально крепился, как и рассказывают, действительно без гвоздей, деревянными нагелями — стержнями. Только позднее, при перестройках и реставрациях стали использовать небольшие гвозди.

Comment: Посмотрел еще пословицы, гвоздь-страдание - это что-то восточное. Тот, кто любит, вбивает гвоздь в свое сердце. - индийская пословица). Вообще гвозди западные - это именно гвозди или какие-то полезные элементы. А у нас вот бывает, Даль: Гвозди на столе, и пиру конец! Гвоздистый, гвоздеватый, гвоздковатый, наполненный гвоздями, истыканный забитыми гвоздями. Старая, гвоздистая доска.Гвоздастый человек, кто гвоздит, драчун, гвоздач, гвоздила. Гвоздюха ж. загвоздка, остолбуха, удар кулаком, особ. в голову.

Comment: Западное мышление зацикленное, а восточное в бесконечность ушло.  Как лучше?

Comment: А нужно "лучше"? Но вы поняли о чём я.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примеры ниже — фразы, суть которых в напутствии или требовании конкретного результата (*Требовал, чтобы все программы, фильмы и спектакли шли не дольше сорока пяти минут. Сорок пять — и никаких гвоздей; Жить — и никаких гвоздей; Светить и никаких гвоздей; Ехать, сказал, тебе в Маргаритовку, и никаких гвоздей!*), где градус строгости повышен не знаком, а словом,  и фразы — оценочные сообщения с легко улавливаемым смыслом: *А беляки сидят в блиндажах да теплушечках, и никаких гвоздей* (без хлопот); *Либо за, либо против — и никаких гвоздей* (третьего не дано); *Свобода и — никаких гвоздей* (без вариантов); *Взял и пришел. И никаких гвоздей!* (он прост).

Если в последних проблемное словосочетаание самостоятельно и по контексту определяется читателем, то первые, являясь только эмоцией, могут быть замещены восклицательным знаком или синонимами (*И точка*; *Я сказал*).

Обе группы, тем не менее, используя одну устойчивую форму, утверждающую либо отсутствие препятствий, либо то, что ими следует пренебречь (*загвоздочка вышла*) ради большего. Гвоздь как препятствие нетрудно встретить и в наши дни, но раньше больше проблем он приносил тем, кто разбирал срубы изб, бань, храмов для вынужденного или планового переноса строений в другие места. Попросту гвозди в правильно срубленных соединениях не нужны, но без них и прочих метизов *кое-где у нас порой* работа не делалась. Гвозди в полу, в стене, гвозди сапожные также часто являлись некоторым препятствием и бедствием для миллионов людей. Для домоседа и гвоздь мебельный может стать раздражителем и препятствием.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно! Голос от меня. Значит, фраза  неоднозначная: просто эмоции, отсутствие вариантов, категоричность  оценок и требований.

Answer (score 0):

**Миниатюра "И никаких гвоздей!"**

```
 „История — это гвоздь, на который я вешаю свою картину.“ —  
  Александр Дюма (отец) Александр Дюма-Старший, великий 
  французский писатель 1802–1870
```

1. **Вот вроде бы интересный вопрос,** надо ответить.

Сейчас посмотрим...  О, да здесь все просто, правило-то  известное, со школы еще помню.  Тогда зачем что-то изобретать? Сначала вступление, потом вот отсюда спишем, ну а дальше вывод, понятное дело. Всё, ответ готов, ну разве я не гений! **Проблема решена — и никаких гвоздей!**

2. Что значит непонятно?  Куда уж понятнее? Третий раз уже вам объясняю! Да с вами разговаривать, что **гвозди в камень забивать,** только время зря потеряешь. Мое решение правильное — **и никаких гвоздей!**
3. Другие иначе думают? А что мне до других, зачем мне их слушать! Важно, что я так думаю —  **и никаких гвоздей.**  У меня всё точка в точку, как **гвоздь в бочку.** Что это значит? А я-то откуда знаю.